# modify recent commit message list

Tags: tortoisesvn

When committing, tortoisesvn allows you to select a messasge from the "Recent message" queue (see http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html)

When a merge is performed with tortoisesvn, it automatically generates a commit message and put it in the recent commit message history queue. This way, it is possible to open the commit menu and easily select it.

Having created my own svn workflow with scripts, I would like to do the same. Is it it possible?

I have searched for known strings in .svn or Subversion config dir, but but could not find the list to edit.

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.7.7.

Comment: Would a simple `svn log --verbose -r $start_revision $repos_url ` be able to give you those existing log message?

Comment: @VonC I don't want to display the list. I want to edit it.

Comment: Understood. I was focusing first on getting those logs.